# Displaying JSON Data in AngularJS in array

Tags: php, angularjs, json, model-view-controller

I'm new to angularjs. I'm trying to display data from a php controller returned to server. I'm fetching that data in angular but there is a problem since data is not getting displayed. my code is attached.
**Controller Action Method**

```
public function actionAhmed(){
$unit = Units::model()->findAll();
$unitList = array();
foreach($unit as $value){
$unitList[] = $value->attributes;
}
return json_encode($unitList);  
}
```

**Angular Controller**

```
    var myModel = angular.module('MyModel', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/tutorial/index.php/units/ahmed')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.parsedData = response.data;
});    
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<div ng-app="MyModel" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in parsedData">
        {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is data coming under `.then` function

Comment: sorry i didnt get u. im new to web

Comment: add `console.log(response.data)` to check the data is coming

Comment: Are you `echo`ing the returned results from that `actionAhmed()` function?

Comment: data is not coming

Comment: im trying to displaying them @AlonEitan

Comment: @AhmadBinShafaat I'm just want to be sure that you're not confusing `return` with `echo` - It's fine to return a value from a function, but if you want to _return_ that function to the client via an AJAX request, then you must `echo` it - This makes the returned value **from the function** to be **outputted** to the browser

Comment: if i type API address in browser then data is displayed @Bartosz T

Comment: if i use echo statement like echo json_encode($unitList); then data is displayed in browser. now i have to fetch this data and display it another page in angularjs. @AlonEitan

Comment: @AhmadBinShafaat Not sure if I understand - Did you fixed it, or do you still having issues with the code?

Comment: I have fixed it @AlonEitan

Comment: @AhmadBinShafaat Good to hear. Good luck :)